# Hashes vs Arrays In Ruby (Am I using them right?)

Tags: ruby, arrays, architecture, hash

I am essentially building a calendar. Each day is either considered an on day or an off day. It can't be both. I take the users input and generate a calendar for the next 365 days out using what is basically a test condition.

I believe I should use a hash for this using the date as a key. I read that as long as I use ruby 1.9 the hashes stay in order and I can iterate through them like an array if I so choose. I believe I will iterate through them when I display the calendar.

Is this the correct way of thinking about it?

Comment: It might be a little easier for you to go with a data structure that only tells which days are 'on' days, rather than having an artificially large hash/array? Just a thought..

Comment: @Chris Okay, thanks for the input. I'm not sure how that would work out, but I think I'll head in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has a [set class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html), which you could use to store "on" dates. Since sets internally are implemented as hashes, lookups are fast. Example (more or less a slighly tidied up IRB session):

```
require 'set' 
require 'date'

on_days = Set.new
on_days << Date.today + 1
on_days << Date.today + 7

def on_day?(on_days, date_to_check)
  on_days.include? date_to_check
end 
>> on_day?(on_days, Date.today) #=> false
>> on_day?(on_days, Date.today+1) #=> true
```

In a real program you'd probably wrap this up in a class, with `on_days` as an instance variable instead of passing it around, but the principle should be the same.